# Scp through ssh tunnel opened

Tags: ssh, scp, ssh-tunnel

I want to send files from machineA which has opened a reverse tunnel with a server.   The reverse tunnel connects port 22 on machineA with port 2222 on the server:

```
autossh -M 0 -q -f -N -o "ServerAliveInterval 120" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 1" -R 2222:localhost:22 userserver@server.com
```

If I do:

```
scp file userserver@server.com:.
```

then SCP sends the file with a new login over SSH, in my case using public/private key.

But if I do:

```
scp -P 2222 file userserver@localhost:.
```

I get a "connection refused" message. The same happens if I replace `2222` above with the port found with:

```
netstat | grep ssh | grep ESTABLISHED
```

How I can send files without opening a new ssh connection (without handshake)?

Comment: Please edit your question to show how you set up the SSH tunnel which scp is supposed to use.

Comment: I added the command to launch the reverse ssh tunnel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ControlMaster` option in your `ssh_config` (`~/.ssh/config`), which will create persistent connection for further ssh/scp/sftp sessions. It is easy as pie:

```
Host yourhost
  Hostname fqdn.tld
  Port port_number # if required, but probably yes, if you do port-forwarding
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPath ~/.ssh/master-%r@%h
  ControlPersist 5m
```

Comment: if I try this config and I setup port with 2222 value I get a connection refused message. I tested with 22 port executing scp --v and this work. Thanks