# Optimizing SCP over network

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scp

I have a shell script which sends a file using scp over the network. The script works in an event driven fashion i.e. every time the file is modified,it is sent over the network using scp. I would like to optimize the script such that instead of every time sending the file, I only send the "new appended/new write data" and that gets appended to the file at the other endpoint

The script is as follows

```
while true
do
inotifywait -e close_write,moved_to,create  . |
while read -r directory events filename; do
  if [ "$filename" = "keylog.txt" ]; then
     sshpass -p "password" scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no keylog.txt machine@192.168.151.19:/home/machine/keylog.txt 
  fi
done
sleep 0.00001
done
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scp through ssh tunnel opened](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33735624/scp-through-ssh-tunnel-opened)

Comment: Can you please explain how is this a possible duplicate to the referenced question ?. I would be willing to take down the question if it is the case.

Comment: The titles are misleading. It is trying to make more separate `scp` requests to the remote server faster. The most of the time you spend in connecting to the server, not transferring files! Therefore it can be interesting to read for you through that. Obviously, you can reuse that even with `rsync` to achieve both diff transfer and faster transmissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to take a look at `rsync`.
It's designed exactly for this kind of purposes.
Quoting from `man rsync`:

> ```
>    Rsync is a fast and extraordinarily versatile file copying tool.   It  can
>    copy  locally,  to/from  another  host over any remote shell, or to/from a
>    remote rsync daemon.  It offers a large number  of  options  that  control
>    every aspect of its behavior and permit very flexible specification of the
>    set of files to be copied.  It is famous for its delta-transfer algorithm,
>    which reduces the amount of data sent over the network by sending only the
>    differences between the source files and the existing files in the  desti-
>    nation.  Rsync is widely used for backups and mirroring and as an improved
>    copy command for everyday use.
> ```

On a server that supports `scp`,
typically `rsync` works too.
Try this:

```
sshpass -p "password" rsync keylog.txt machine@192.168.151.19:/home/machine/keylog.txt
```

Even without tuning the parameters,
`rsync` will try to minimize the amount of data transferred.
When the destination file already exists,
it will transfer only the necessary difference.

Comment: I ran the commands with the time option. 
The time taken with rsync is 0.328ms while with the scp command is 0.283ms.

Comment: @AbhimanyuKhanna, this benchmark is too short to be relevant.

Comment: @AbhimanyuKhanna - `rsync` supports efficient handling of sparse files as well with `-S`. I always use the compress option `-z`.